# How to check if an axes handle is cleared or not

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I want to check if some axes have been cleared or not, based on which some further task is to be performed. I use `cla` to clear some axes, not `delete`. For example:

```
figure

hs1 = subplot(121); plot(rand(100,2), 'x');

hs2 = subplot(122); plot(rand(100,2), 'o');

cla(hs1)
```

Then, the question is how to determine if `hs1` is cleared.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [`cla`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cla.html) function removes all child objects with [visible handles](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/preventing-access-to-figures-and-axes.html) by default. You can therefore check if an axes has been cleared by seeing if it has any [child objects](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.graphics.axis.axes-properties.html;jsessionid=90f595aad631d30af1f2af15606a#budumk7_sep_shared-Children) using the [`allchild`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/allchild.html) function:

```
isCleared = isempty(allchild(hs1));
```

A couple notes to keep in mind:

- The `cla` function will not clear objects with *hidden* handles by default. The option `cla(hs1, 'reset')` is needed to clear hidden handles.
- The `allchild` function will find all child objects regardless of their handle visibility. If you just want to check for child objects with visible handles, you can use `isempty(hs1.Children)`.

Comment: @gnonice: Correct!  An alternative I just found is: isempty(hs1.Children)

Comment: @jingweimo: Yes, that's another option, but it will only show child objects with visible handles. `allchild` shows everything, including hidden handles.